# Make TextBox uneditable

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, textbox

I want to make some `TextBox`es on my form uneditable, but I want the `text` to be clear (black not gray) and that's why I do not want to use

`myTextBox.Enabled = false;`

Somehow I want it to be disabled but with non-gray fore-color.

Does anyone have any clue?

Comment: why -1 -1 -1? I see, the answer is one word, OK, but I really didn't know that one word. Shouldn't I ask?

Comment: well dont worry! few people just dont understand

Comment: :) you're right @AppDeveloper, I'm sure everyone has some dark points which need to be brightened. Thanks for your kind reply. Good luck.

Comment: just remove text box and place there the label

Comment: @UthistranS. - what if later he needs the input from user in the same box ?

Comment: @AppDeveloper : label.text = "User input"... anytime

Comment: @UthistranS. not a good suggestion my friend, that way I'll lose the fixed location and size and also the text wrapping mode. A label streches to it's content length, but a textbox has a fixed size and shows the text in multilines (wrapping behaviour) but label needs more code to maintain this behaviour.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change the font color of a disabled TextBox?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/276179/how-to-change-the-font-color-of-a-disabled-textbox)

Answer (score 132, accepted):

Using the [`TextBox.ReadOnly`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.readonly%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) property

```
TextBox.ReadOnly = true;
```

For a Non-Grey background you can change the [`TextBox.BackColor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2kh9x59.aspx) property to `SystemColors.Window` Color

```
textBox.BackColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.Window;
```

> When this property is set to true, the contents of the control cannot
>   be changed by the user at runtime. With this property set to true, you
>   can still set the value of the Text property in code. You can use this
>   feature instead of disabling the control with the Enabled property to
>   allow the contents to be copied and ToolTips to be shown.

Comment: The property is ```TextBox.IsReadOnly``` for WPF .NET 4.5.2, Visual Studio 2015, Update 3 (it says Version 14.0.25431.01 Update 3).

Answer (score 18):

Use the [ReadOnly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.readonly%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) property on the TextBox.

```
myTextBox.ReadOnly = true;
```

But Remember: [TextBoxBase.ReadOnly Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.readonly%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

> When this property is set to true, the contents of the control
>   **cannot be changed by the user at runtime**. With this property set to true, you can **still set the value of the Text property in code**.
>   You can use this feature instead of disabling the control with the
>   Enabled property to allow the contents to be copied and ToolTips to be
>   shown.

Answer (score 6):

You can try using:

```
textBox.ReadOnly = true;
textBox.BackColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.Window;
```

The last line is only neccessary if you want a non-grey background color.

Answer (score 4):

Just set in XAML:

```
        <TextBox IsReadOnly="True" Style="{x:Null}" />
```

So that text will not be grayed-out.

Answer (score 3):

If you want your `TextBox` uneditable you should make it [ReadOnly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.readonly%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it using XAML set the property `isReadOnly` to `true`.

Comment: This is a off-topic answer for this question. Because this quesion is ask about winform not WPF.

Answer (score 1):

This is for GridView.

```
 grid.Rows[0].Cells[1].ReadOnly = true;
```

Answer (score -1):

Enabled="false" in aspx page

Comment: Hi Suraj, welcome to Stackoverflow. Thanks for your effort. My question is actually about Windows Forms Applications. Tags help us put our questions in the proper category.